Show that there is also a randomized polynomial-time decider $M'$ for $L$ such that $w\in L \Rightarrow Pr[M(w)=1] > 0.99$
The question is suppose there is a randomized polynomial-time decider $M$ for a language $L$ such that:

$w\in L \Rightarrow Pr[M(w)=1]>0.1$
$w\not\in L \Rightarrow Pr[M(w)=1]=0 $

Show that there is also a randomized polynomial-time decider $M'$ for $L$ such that:

$w\in L \Rightarrow Pr[M’(w)=1]>0.99$
$w\not\in L \Rightarrow Pr[M’(w)=1]=0 $

My idea is to run $M$ a large number of times to amplify the probability of success, and I will use the Chernoff Bound to find the number of times to run $M$. Suppose I need to run $M$ $n$ times. The formula is $Pr[X\leq (1-\delta)\mu]\leq e^{-\delta^2\mu/2}$. I let $\delta$ be 0.99 because $\delta$ represents the least upper bound. $\mu=0.1n$. Hence, $(1-\delta)\mu=(1-0.99)0.1n=0.01n$. $Pr[X\leq 0.01n]\leq e^{-0.99^2(0.1n)/2} = e^{-0.049005n}$. $Pr[X\leq 0.01n]\leq 0.01$ hence I calculate that $n\approx 94$. I need to construct a new poly-time decider $M'$ that runs $M$ for $94$ times to amplify the probability of success from $0.1$ to $0.99$. However, I'm unsure if my idea is correct. I appreciate any feedback.

Weren't you meant to use $M'$ in your probabilities?

@Nathaniel you mean in my calculation for $\mu$?

No, but in the result you wanted to prove.

Since the decider $M$ has no false positive, there is no need for Chernoff bound. Consider $M'$ defined as follow:

run $M(x)$ $n$ times;
if $M$ returns $1$ at least once, then $M'$ returns $1$;
otherwise, $M'$ returns $0$.

Then let us analyse $M'$:

if $x\notin L$, since $M$ has no false positive, all executions of $M(x)$ will return $0$, and $\mathbb{P}(M'(x) = 1) = 0$;
if $x\in L$, then:
$$\mathbb{P}(M'(x) = 1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(M'(x) = 0) = 1 - \left(\mathbb{P}(M(x) = 0)\right)^n \geqslant 1 - (0.9)^n$$

What you want is $1-(0.9)^n\geqslant 0.99$, meaning $0.01\geqslant (0.9)^n$, and $\log(0.01) \geqslant n\log(0.9)$, hence $n\geqslant \dfrac{\log(0.01)}{\log(0.9)}\simeq 44$.

If I want to use the majority vote method, would I need to use Chernoff bound?

As you have seen, I didn't use Chernoff bound. It would be necessary to improve the probability of success in the case of an algorithm that can have false negative AND false positive, but not here.
